# OCaml read \n character

Tags: string, ocaml

I have the following code to read lines from a file

```
let read_file filename =
  let lines = ref [] in
  let chan = open_in filename in
  try
    while true do
      lines := input_line chan :: !lines
    done;
    !lines
  with End_of_file ->
    close_in chan;
    List.rev !lines
```

However, this code adds additional "\" to characters "\n". 
E.g.

```
helloworld\n
```

gets read into

```
helloworld\\n
```

How shall I turn off this so that I get `helloworld\n` instead?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

So I have tested with this:

```
let read_file filename =
  let lines = ref [] in
  let chan = open_in filename in
  try
    while true do
      lines := input_line chan :: !lines
    done;
    !lines
  with End_of_file ->
    close_in chan;
    List.rev !lines

let () =
  let lines = read_file "test.txt" in
  for i=1 to List.length lines
  do
    Printf.printf("%s") (List.nth lines (i-1))
  done;
```

test.txt

```
helloworld\n
```

The output is `helloworld\n` instead of `helloworld` with a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously doubt that extra characters are being introduced by this code. Most likely you're just misreading the output of the toplevel. If you write out the string with `print_string` you'll see the actual contents.

I assume your input line actually contains `helloworld\n` (12 characters, plus the newline at the end).

Here is a test session on OS X 10.9.2

```
$ od -c myfile
0000000    h   e   l   l   o   w   o   r   l   d   \   n  \n        
0000015
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let read_file filename =
... copy your definition above ...
# let lines = read_file "myfile";;
val lines : string list = ["helloworld\\n"]
# String.length (List.nth lines 0);;
- : int = 12
# print_string (List.nth lines 0);;
helloworld\n- : unit = ()
```

The line length is correct (12 chars). The extra backslash is just the way the toplevel writes a backslash in a string.

**Update**

Your test file apparently contains an actual `\n` (two characters), so naturally this is what shows up on the output. If you don't want the `\n` to show up in the output, you should remove it from the input :-)

**Update 2**

I can't shake the feeling that you might not be used to thinking about text files at a low level. If this is true, here are some things to think about.

- Lines in a Unix style text file *already* have newlines at the end. You don't need to put `\n` in the file to represent the end of the line. Your text editor (or other text handling app) will put newlines in for you at the ends of lines.
- The OCaml function `input_line` *removes* these newlines (because they're redundant--there's one at the end of every line).
- If you want these newlines to appear in your list of lines, you can add them back yourself with `input_line chan ^ "\n"` or similar.
- Or you can write lines out using `print_endline` which writes the newline for you.

(My apologies if you already knew about this.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I get the same result. I may have phrased this wrong but I want "helloworld\n" such that when I run print, it prints out "helloworld" and a new line instead of "\n".

Comment: That's what it will do if you print the string. It's just the toplevel that shows the extra backslash (to eliminate ambiguity in intrepreting the result of the REPL).

Comment: If you want `\n` (two characters) in the input file to be translated to a newline (one character) on output, you'll have to write code that does the translation. It's not going to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for the parsing with `Str.regexp`

```
let newlinereg = Str.regexp "\\\\n" in                                                                                                                                                      
let replacednewline = Str.global_replace newlinereg "\n" output_string in                                                                                                                                                              
let tabreg = Str.regexp "\\\\t" in                                                                                                                                                  
let final_string = Str.global_replace tabreg "\t" replacednewline in
final_string;;
```